# Wordpress 504 Gateway Time-out at install and when adding user

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress

I'm having some issues with my WordPress installation. I'm running it on a VPS server. I installed my own LEMP stack. When running the WordPress installation, after the final step, it takes some time to load and finally, gives a `504 Gateway Time-out` error. But the site is installed and I can login to the admin panel.

Inside the admin panel, I when I try to create a user, same thing happens. But the user is created. The strange thing is, the user does not get an email with the details even if I tick the box to send them.

My nginx error logs look like this:

```
    PHP message: WordPress database error Table 'tkdpw39sna2.d3gsO9d_options' doesn't exist for query INSERT INTO `d3gsO9d_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('rewrite_rules', '', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`) made by wp_install, flush_rewrite_rules, WP_Rewrite->flush_rules, update_option, add_option" while reading upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/install.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/install.php?step=1"
    2017/06/28 04:39:08 [error] 32272#32272: *72 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/install.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/install.php?step=1"
    2017/06/28 04:45:31 [error] 32272#32272: *143 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/user-new.php"
    2017/06/28 04:51:27 [error] 32272#32272: *183 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/user-new.php"
    2017/06/28 10:22:12 [notice] 32477#32477: signal process started
    2017/06/28 10:24:38 [notice] 32490#32490: signal process started
    2017/06/28 10:27:12 [error] 32491#32491: *199 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/user-new.php"
    2017/06/28 10:44:16 [emerg] 32674#32674: "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/white_admin:20
    2017/06/28 10:45:56 [error] 32707#32707: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WordPress database error Unknown column 'f45o3Kp_' in 'field list' for query SELECT f45o3Kp_" while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1"
    2017/06/28 10:50:25 [error] 32707#32707: *24 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/user-new.php"
    2017/06/28 10:57:41 [error] 3520#3520: *5 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/user-new.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/user-new.php"
```

Note that I have tried installing and re-installing several times. This is the last few lines of the log. Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

I would start by checking those entries

> [emerg] 32674#32674: "fastcgi_index" directive is duplicate in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/white_admin:20
>       2017/06/28 10:45:56
>
> [error] 32707#32707: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: WordPress database error Unknown column 'f45o3Kp_' in 'field list' for query SELECT f45o3Kp_" while reading response header from upstream, client: 112.135.4.109, server: admin.whiteberryinteriors.com, request: "POST /wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "admin.whiteberryinteriors.com", referrer: "http://admin.whiteberryinteriors.com/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=1"
>       2017/06/28 10:50:25 [error]

It's likely that you have something to verify in your vhost and in your database. If it's a new install and you did some experiment you could simply delete the db and reinstall. Last I would check the timeout configurations for php.